# lines of curvature of parallel surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

The picture below is from Born & Wolf: Principles of Optics, 7th ed,, page 123, and is concerned with the propagation of optical wave fronts in a homogeneous medium.

The wave fronts are parallel in the sense that given one equi-phase surface (wave front), say, $\mathcal S_1$ then one can generate another by erecting the surface normal $\mathbf N(\mathcal P)$ on each point $\mathcal P \in \mathcal S_1$ and marking all points that are the same distance, say, $a$ from the foot $\mathcal P$ of the normal $\mathbf N(\mathcal P)$. These are the points $\mathcal Q \in \mathcal S_2$ where $\mathbf q = \mathbf p + a \mathbf N(\mathcal P)$ denote the position vectors corresponding to the points.

In the argument below, Born & Wolf are implying that if a point $\mathcal P$ is on either of the two *lines of curvature* then on any of its parallel surfaces, arbitrary $a$, the corresponding point $\mathcal Q$ will also lie on one of the lines of curvature, presumably the same min or max or curvature as the one on which the starting point is.

This sounds right but my question is how to prove this statement?

[image]

Comment: It’s hard to address your question without knowing your differential geometry knowledge. The easiest answer is to compare the Gauss mappings of the surface and its parallel surface.

Comment: @TedShifrin I have read Struik...

Comment: So assume the $u$- and $v$-curves are lines of curvature in the surface, parametrized by $x$. Now differentiate $x+rn$ and see what the first and second fundamental forms will be.

Comment: @TedShifrin OK, I was afraid you would say that; do  you know of a handwaving "physically" more pleasing proof?

Comment: You asked for a proof. A handwave is to note that as you follow the normal vector outward, it stays normal to the parallel surfaces. So any line of curvature — curve of maximal/minimal bending — will propagate as a line of curvature. The actual proof is not a big deal, since, following what I suggested, you get $(x+rn)_u = x_u - rk_1 x_u = (1-rk_1)x_u$ and similarly for the $v$ partial.

Comment: @TedShifrin. Thank you. "Handwaving" is the a wrong word, I should have said "visual" or "intuitive". Anyhow, I have a sort of "visual" way but I am not quite happy with it. I read (Wardle) that "Theorem 3.19. A curve C on a surface S is a line of curvature if and only if the normals to S along C form a developable surface $\Sigma$. From this the answer to my question follows from the common rays are normal to *both* surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ and because the normals of $S_1$ along the edge is developable ("only if"), hence the same normals will also produce a line of curvature on $S_2$ ("if").

Comment: @TedShifrin But what I was hoping for is an argument that makes it obvious from ray to surface orthogonality that the curves of $S_2$ must have extreme normal curvatures if they have it at other end on $S_1$. Is there such argument that makes this *obvious*?

Comment: Only a computation makes it obvious (and proven) to me. Yes, the exercise on developable surfaces gives an argument, but I only know how to prove that with a (less obvious) computation.